# Erratic text input problem with CudaText editor

Tags: text-editor, input

I found myself needing a text editor that would handle a large (44Mb) XML file happily. I ran across [CudaText](http://uvviewsoft.com/cudatext/) (licensed under Mozilla Public License 2.0), a newish cross-platform text editor that has been [well reviewed](https://itsfoss.com/cudatext-code-editor/).

With `apt search cudatext`, I found it was available to install via `sudo apt install`, and did so. (It's also available in the Ubuntu Software "app store".) It did indeed handle my large XML file without breaking a sweat, and I got my editing done...

...but it wasn't easy, for an odd reason. It seemed to capture/record only occasional keystrokes, although I managed to get my edits done using copy/paste and using another text editor to create the strings needed.

I posted this as [an issue in the dev's Github repo](https://github.com/Alexey-T/CudaText/issues/1605), and he cannot replicate my experience. Here's what I posted (slightly re-formatted, and now updated):

> For some reason, I cannot type text into the editor. It doesn't matter whether the file is "new", or whether I open an existing file for editing. The size doesn't matter. The same thing happens in the other "fields" that take user input (e.g., "find", or "command palette" filter).
>
> If I'm in the main editing window, it seems like when I type FAST, I have a better chance of the keystroke being recognized, but if I type at a normal rate, only the rare keystroke is recorded/echoed, nor are they saved if the file is saved -- i.e., it is not an issue about displaying to the screen, but the keystroke actually being recorded. The arrow keys don't work at all to position the cursor.
>
> There are two exceptions to this erratic input behaviour:
>
> 1. striking the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key always is recognized, as is the <kbd>Backspace</kbd> key, **UNLESS** I use the arrow keys to position the cursor (which disappears): then neither <kbd>Enter</kbd> nor <kbd>Backspace</kbd> work, until I use a mouse-click to position the cursor explicitly -- then both are back to normal; and
> 2. if I paste text (after Ctrl-C from a different app), then it is recognized and inputs correctly. This is how I managed to edit my large XML file successfully (I typed my string into a different text editor, copied, then pasted it into the CudaText window).
>
> I have searched this issue list, and can't find anyone else having the problem. I saw the "opposite" problem in [#855](https://github.com/Alexey-T/CudaText/issues/855) and checked my input method. I'm using IBus (not XIM), but even setting my input method to "none" made no difference to CudaText.

I thought I would see if any AskUbuntu types have had this experience? Or any suggestions for coaxing it into behaving properly? It seems like a helpful tool, but frustrating if it doesn't accept input properly.

I'm on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case anyone else gets hit with this: the issue did indeed appear to be with having `xim` as the system's input method.

I struggled to get my "input method" to `none` but ... my system changes seem now to have "stuck". At first, it kept coming up `xim` no matter what I did. But now my system settings show "none" for "input method", and I get this when checking in terminal:

```
$ im-config -m
default
none
ibus

ibus
```

And CudaText is now accepting input perfectly. I'm not sure why I had such a hard time with this, but it's good to know that this configuration fixes the issue I had.